# Map 2D coordinate to CSS3 3D transformed <div>?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a  tag which has been manipulated by using the rotate3d() transform. It looks fine, but I want to be able to match up my positioning of the div with (flat, 2D) content I have placed above it.

Is there any way to 'map' a 2D coordinate to the  tag's 3D space, and vice versa? i.e. I pass in an X and Y, and then receive a transformed X and Y coordinate through the rotate3d() transform?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but the wikipedia entry on perspective projection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection is pretty decent